# Is a constant (deterministic random variable) Gaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Consider a constant $c$. Is this constant a Gaussian random variable (i.e. is $c\sim\mathcal{N}(c,0)$)?

I realize a constant is easily described as a discrete random variable, but I wish to use normal random variable properties on constants when combining them with other continuous random variables.

It makes sense to me that this should be, but it leads to a delta function for the pdf which I assume is bad form.

Comment: You can use some procedures but not others.  For example there is no linear transformation which takes it to a standard Gaussian distribution.  But you can add its mean and variance to other Gaussian distributions (it is independent of them) and still have a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: In some sense, you can consider a constant $c$ as a Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu=c$ and variance $\sigma^2=0$. For example, the characteristic function of a Gaussian random variable of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is given by $e^{imt}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2t^2}$ and for $\sigma=0$ this gives $e^{i\mu t}$, that is precisely the characteristic function of the constant variable $\mu$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantages of considering Dirac distributions as normal distributions (with variance zero) outweigh the disadvantages. For example, one wants to define a family of random variables as normal if every linear combination of this family has a one-dimensional normal distribution. This would not be correct if Dirac distributions were not normal.